# Wordpress multi level category templates

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, categories

I'm developing a theme for a client who wants to display his products through a multi level category's pages.

Lets say that my products are chairs. My client wants the first page to display the chair's manufacturers. User selects manufacturer and goes to the next template which displays all the types of chairs for the selected manufacturer e.g. wooden chairs or metallic chairs and finally when the user selects the type, the next template will display all the chairs of the selected type of the selected manufacturer.

**Example link:**

> domain.com/chairs/american-chairs/wooden-chairs/template-with-chairs

Ηow can I achieve this kind of functionality more effectively? Right now I have created a different page for chairs' manufacturers and a page from chairs' types where I query all the products.

Comment: Have you tried url queries and then having the page template create a query depending on the supplied values? e.g. domain.com/chairs?style=american-chairs&type=wooden-chairs.

Comment: For that example i have to make a page chairs and the user have to select both style and type of chairs.I would like to choose style first and then the available types of the selected style (previous page).thanks

Comment: use a cpt and custom taxonomy.

Comment: I already have a cpt with custom taxonomy where i have staructure my categories like the example above.